# Масштабирование в окне браузера

Tags: html, css

Пытался сделать адаптивную страницу сайта и выявил такую проблему. Когда открываю сайт на телефоне, либо планшете - все в порядке, но при изменении размера самого браузера - тег media будто не работает. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Ссылка на сайт: http://cr27532.tmweb.ru/glowna/

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Теперь слетела и  верстка и под мобильные телефоны

Comment: надо изначально когда начинаешь верстать сайт - вставлять этот мета тег - но можешь убрать/заменить  user-scalable=0, на  user-scalable=no,

Comment: Получается уже ничего сделать нельзя и все нужно будет делать заново?

Comment: да вроде бы всё прилично получилось - только вот те блоки что внизу - длинные - их уменьшить или под скролл убрать в мобилке

Comment: Это если через инструменты разработчика сжимать. Но там и раньше все нормально было. А вот если просто вручную уменьшить окно браузера, то все элементы вылазят друг на друга. Я не могу понять причину. То есть на реальных устройствах все ок, а сжатом браузере - все криво

Comment: нет нет , причём окно браузера ? проверяй в смартфонах ...я например посмотрел в трёх разных смартфонах

Comment: Так в том и дело. В смартфонах, планшетах все работало и раньше. Я же специально для них верстку делал. Просто заказчик тестит именно сжимая браузер(я сам это узнал вчера и немного был в шоке) и ничего доказать не могу. Вот думаю должен же быть способ какой-то.

Comment: момент - я проверю

Comment: тогда надо переделать - от меньшего к большему разрешению

Comment: И как это сделать? Прописывать media для  большего количества разрешений?

Comment: ну мне для подобных лендингов хватало 3 -5 запросов ,  ну это индивидуально - увидел что то перескочило или что то воткнулось куда то и сразу запрос на изменение каких то свойств

Comment: А как вы хотели? Конечно медия запрос делать. Надо было делать на флексах, и то  там медия запросы надо делать, или на гриде.$screen-xs-start: 360px !default;
screen-xs-end: 599.99px !default;
screen-sm-start: 600px !default;
screen-sm-end: 899.99px !default;
screen-md-start: 900px !default;
screen-md-end: 1199.99px !default;
screen-lg-start: 1200px !default;
screen-lg-end: 1799.99px !default;
screen-xl-start: 1800px !default;